# How to hide .php extension with htaccess inside admin or other folder

Tags: php, .htaccess

So this is my code to hide .php extension

```
RewriteEngine On

# Force https.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Redirect non www to www excluding subdomains.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.*)\.(.*)\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Hide php extension.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

The hompage index.php file is working, I mean I can access the http://www.site.tld without issues but if I try to use http://www.site.tld/admin/ it give me a 404 error.

> Not Found
>   The requested URL /admin/.php was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

EDIT:
If i delete the redirect # Redirect non www to www excluding subdomains. code lines is working.

Comment: You should implement another htaccess file into admin folder with same code.

Comment: @AnkitMishra no! That only makes things confusing and hard to debug. All rules should be inside a single location. Preferably not in a dynamic configuration file (.htaccess), but in the real host configuration.

Comment: The reason for that error is obvious: if you request `http://www.site.tld/admin/`, then the rule does what you told it to, it appends a `.php` to the path. you need to take care that your rule only gets applied if the request URL is _not_ a folder!

Comment: @arkascha hmm.,actually i am a beginner made a website i my last project with admin panel and used another htaccess in admin folder that's works fine for me.I was not aware that this can be achieved with a single htaccess ,I will learn this today. Thanxx for suggest

Comment: @AnkitMishra Certainly it is possible to use multiple such dynamic configuration files, but that only makes sense if you want to implement specific request handling rules for a specific folder. So that requests to that specific folder are handled _different_ to requests to other folders. Otherwise you'd have to copy that file _for each folder you create_ which certainly does not make any sense, does not scale and will certainly be forgotten...

Answer (score 0):

I changed the hide extension code to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [NC,END]
```

and now is working.

Comment: That first rule creates an endless loop, what sense does that make? The only reason it does _not_ crash the site is because the rewritint module is intelligent enough to realize the loop. I assume you want to implement an exception here preventing the application of the following rule, but that is _exactly_ what `RewriteCond`itions are for...

Comment: The second rule will work if a trailing slash is specified, but not if that is missing. So if thisworks for you that is only because some other rule automatically adds such a trailing slash to the request, which means an additional round trip of requests...